# Replacing footnotes with sidenotes in Classicthesis

Tags: footnotes, classicthesis, sidenotes

I'm planning to use `classicthesis` for my PhD research, and I would like to know if there is a way to replace footnotes with sidenotes (with hyperlinks, etc). Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{sidenotes}

\begin{document}
This is a\sidenote{goes to side} side note. 

Some text and another\sidenotemark\ one which is not here  but some where else and its mark is alone here.

But here\sidenotetext{go to the side and span more than one line  if possible}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Though the same can be achieved with `marginnote` package, `sidenote` gives extra facilities like `\sidenotemark` and `\sidenotetext`.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, Harish. Thanks a lot for your reply! :)

Comment: @user1392124 You are welcome. Glad it helped. :)